# Reverse Polish notation based compiler

Tags: perl, assembly, math-expression-eval, compiler, forth

**Description**

- Very small subset of Forth
- This is a proof of concept level compiler, no optimizations or over/underflow checking
- See the embedded POD for more information
- NASM is used as assembler
- gcc is used to link with glibc
- 32bit ELF Binary is generated

**bhathiforth.pl**

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw(say);

sub tokenize {
    my $fullcode = shift;
    if ( not defined $fullcode ) {
        die "Invalid Arguments";
    }
    my @tokens;
    while ( $fullcode =~ /([0-9]+|\+|\-|\*|\/|\.)/g ) {
        push @tokens, $1;
    }
    return @tokens;
}

sub generate_assembly {

    my @tokens = @{ $_[0] };
    if ( not @tokens ) {
        die "Invalid Arguments";
    }

    my $assembly = "section .text\nglobal main\nextern printf\nmain:\n";
    say "Tokens";
    say "==================";
    foreach (@tokens) {

        say "<$_>";

        if ( $_ =~ /[0-9]+/ ) {
            $assembly .= "push $_\n";
        }
        elsif ( $_ eq "+" ) {
            $assembly .= "pop ebx\npop eax\nadd eax,ebx\npush eax\n";
        }
        elsif ( $_ eq "-" ) {
            $assembly .= "pop ebx\npop eax\nsub eax,ebx\npush eax\n";
        }
        elsif ( $_ eq "/" ) {
            $assembly .= "mov edx,0\npop ecx\npop eax\ndiv ecx\npush eax\n";
        }
        elsif ( $_ eq "*" ) {
            $assembly .= "mov edx,0\npop ecx\npop eax\nmul ecx\npush eax\n";
        }
        elsif ( $_ eq "." ) {
            $assembly .= "push message\ncall printf\nadd esp, 8\n";
        }
    }
    $assembly .= "ret\nmessage db \"%d\", 10, 0;";
    say "==================";
    return $assembly;
}

my $version = "0.1";

say "Welcome to BhathiFoth compiler v$version";
say "========================================";

my $source = shift @ARGV;
my $output = shift @ARGV;

if ( not defined $source or not defined $output ) {
    say
"Invalid Commandline arguments.\n\nUSAGE:\n% ./bhathiforth.pl <source> <output>";
    exit;
}

open my $CODE, "<", $source or die "Cannot open file '$source'\n:$!";

my ( $line, $fullcode );
$fullcode = "";
while ( $line = <$CODE> ) {
    $fullcode .= $line;
}

close $CODE or die "Cannot close file '$source'\n$!";

my @tokens   = tokenize($fullcode);
my $assembly = generate_assembly( \@tokens );

say "Assembly Code";
say "==================";
say $assembly;
say "==================";

open my $ASM, '>', "$output.asm"
  or die "Cannot open file to write '$output.asm'\n:$!";
print $ASM $assembly;
close $ASM or die "Cannot close file '$output.asm'\n$!";

say "Building Executable...";
system("nasm -f elf $output.asm && gcc -m32 -o $output $output.o");
exit;

# ---------------------------------
# BhathiForth compiler Documentation
# ---------------------------------

=head1 NAME
BhathiForth

=head1 SYNOPSIS
BhathiForth
a reverse polish notation based compiler
(very small subset of forth)
(proof of concept level compiler, no optimizations or over/underflow checking)

=head2 instructions:
    451 [0-9]+ push a number (integers only) to stack
    +   add
    -   minus
    *   multiply
    /   devide
    .   print (adds newline automatically, this will pop the value)
    all other characters are ignored

=head2 information
uses nasm as assembler and gcc to link (depend on c library-glibc)
works only in linux (ELF binary format is used)

=head2 usage
    chmod a+x ./bhathiforth.pl
    ./bhathiforth.pl <source> <output>
=cut  

# --------------------------------
```

**test.b4**

> ```
> 10   push ten
> 10   push ten
> *    pop twice, multiply and push
> .    print top value : this prints hundred
> 200
> 56   push twenty eight
> +
> .    prints two five six
> 256
> 2
> /    
> .    prints one two eight
> 500
> 50
> -
> .    prints four five zero
> ```

**Output**

When executed as `./bhathiforth.pl test.b4 test`:

> ```
> Welcome to BhathiFoth compiler v0.1
> ========================================
> Tokens
> ==================
> <10>
> <10>
> <*>
> <.>
> <200>
> <56>
> <+>
> <.>
> <256>
> <2>
> </>
> <.>
> <500>
> <50>
> <->
> <.>
> ==================
> Assembly Code
> ==================
> section .text
> global main
> extern printf
> main:
> push 10
> push 10
> mov edx,0
> pop ecx
> pop eax
> mul ecx
> push eax
> push message
> call printf
> add esp, 8
> push 200
> push 56
> pop ebx
> pop eax
> add eax,ebx
> push eax
> push message
> call printf
> add esp, 8
> push 256
> push 2
> mov edx,0
> pop ecx
> pop eax
> div ecx
> push eax
> push message
> call printf
> add esp, 8
> push 500
> push 50
> pop ebx
> pop eax
> sub eax,ebx
> push eax
> push message
> call printf
> add esp, 8
> ret
> message db "%d", 10, 0;
> ==================
> Building Executable...
> ```

**Output ELF**

Executed as `./test`:

> ```
> 100
> 256
> 128
> 450
> ```

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8194141/how-to-print-a-number-in-assembly-nasm)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## `tokenize`

The `tokenize` subroutine could be simplified:

```
sub tokenize {
    my ($code) = @_;
    die "Invalid Arguments" unless defined $code;
    return $code =~ m!\d+|[-+*/.]!g;
}
```

Changes include:

- Shorter parameter name
- One-line validation
- Use global match in list context to produce a list of all matches
- Simpler regex that avoids [leaning toothpick syndrome](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leaning_toothpick_syndrome#Pattern_example)

Note that any unrecognized token is treated as a comment, which is quite lenient.

### `generate_assembly`

For readability, I would just pass the tokens as a list rather than as a reference to a list.

I don't recommend printing output as as side-effect: it hinders code reuse.

The assembly code for the operators could be produced by a hash lookup.

### main

A [convention](http://modernperlbooks.com/mt/2009/07/version-confusion.html) for declaring version numbers is

```
our $VERSION = 0.1;
```

An `double_underline()` subroutine could be useful.

```
sub double_underline {
    my ($text) = @_;
    return $text . "\n" . ('=' x len($text));
}

say double_underline("Welcome to BhathiForth compiler v$VERSION");  # Fixed typo "Foth"
```

To read a file fully, you don't need a loop.  Use ["slurp mode"](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#Variables-related-to-filehandles):

```
local $/ = undef;
my $code = <$CODE>;
```

Answer (score 10):

Just one small point that @200_success probably left out so I can say something too:
when matching something against `$_`, for example in `if ($_ =~ /[0-9]+/) { ... }`,
you can simply omit the `$_`:

```
if (/[0-9]+/) {
    # ...
}
```

It's "the default input and pattern-searching space". Read more about the `$_` variable in `man perlvar` or on [perldoc.perl.org](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html).

The main loop in `generate_assembly` rewritten to use this (+ a hashmap for the operators):

```
my %ops = (
    '+' => "pop ebx\npop eax\nadd eax,ebx\npush eax\n",
    '-' => "pop ebx\npop eax\nsub eax,ebx\npush eax\n",
    '/' => "mov edx,0\npop ecx\npop eax\ndiv ecx\npush eax\n",
    '*' => "mov edx,0\npop ecx\npop eax\nmul ecx\npush eax\n",
    '.' => "push message\ncall printf\nadd esp, 8\n",
);
foreach (@tokens) {
    say "<$_>";
    if (/[0-9]+/) {
        $assembly .= "push $_\n";
    } else {
        $assembly .= $ops{$_};
    }
}
```

This made me notice one more point: if I add garbage in the input file like this:

> ```
> 256
> 2
> garbage
> /
> ```

The tokenizer will wipe out "garbage" without a warning.
This could hide some bugs.
I think it would be better to use a more sophisticated parser that can detect syntax errors.

In other words: the language is underspecified. (Thanks [@200_success](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/9357/200-success)!)

Comment: One programmer's comment is another programmers garbage.

Comment: @200_success I updated a bit to clarify the real garbage

Comment: Can you imagine how much code-golfers would like to use this,Ex: non-tokens can be code in another language -> write code that is valid on two compilers.

Answer (score 7):

I'm not a huge fan of reading all input in one one go and transform it in one and then write it in one go. It seems clumsy and will not scale properly (although in the given case it's probably not going to be a problem).

The basic structure I'd go for is this:

```
open my $ASM, '>', "$output.asm"
  or die "Cannot open file to write '$output.asm'\n:$!";

while ( $line = <$CODE> ) {
    @tokens = tokenize($line);
    foreach (@tokens) {
        $assembly = generate_assembly($_);
        print $ASM $assembly;
    }
}

close $ASM or die "Cannot close file '$output.asm'\n$!";
```

`generate_assembly` should just return the assembler output for the given token.

Comment: **NOTE** that generating code as you go will break at the point that the language has to deal with forward references / jump targets.  Although right now that's not a problem, obviously.